Why are types important in model theory?
I have done some work with mathematical structures and computational properties of deciding logical sentences about them. Several people told me that this work uses the fact that the theory I am studying uses "few" types. Thus, I have tried to look around what are these types but I didn't get very well what the topic is about.
So why are types important in model theory? What is the origin of the method?

Here is a related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2880384/7062

@user1868607 Can you maybe add to your question some examples of the structures you are considering? This helps tailor answers (such as more relevant concrete examples, that you asked for in your other comment) and maybe someone can even explain how the "few types" is linked to your situation.

A good place to get started is with compactness arguments.
When doing a compactness argument to construct new models of a theory, one typically adds in a new constant symbol (or several) and specifies a set of properties you want that new constant to satisfy that's consistent and consistent with the base theory. That set of properties is called a partial type.

A concrete example would help even more
